# MSChart with 2 data series - solve in SQL query?

Tags: sql, mschart

I have an MSChart control bound to a SQL query (single series).  All good.

What I need now is to show two separate data series' as separate lines on the chart.  I can write separate queries to each return one of the data sets but I don't believe I can bind the chart control to two separate sqldatasources.

What I can do currently is write the following query.  The two data series are for the average rating of products in two different price bands - 4 and 5 ($0-$10 and >=$10).

SELECT band, AVG(L.rating) as Avg_Rating, date
  FROM PriceBand P
  join ListItem L on L.price >= P.loprice and L.price <= P.hiprice and band > 3
  group by band, loprice, hiprice, date
  order by date, band

which returns data in this form:
2010-12-01 | 4 | 3.1
2010-12-01 | 5 | 3.6
2010-12-02 | 4 | 3.3
2010-12-02 | 5 | 3.9

Date, series, Value

I believe I may need to get it to look like the following.

Date, Value[4], Value[5].

Question 1: Am I correct in the best way to organize the data in order to create the 2-value line chart?

Question 2: If so, how can I rework the query to create that output?

Thanks to all for taking the time to read this and/or assist.

-Dan

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Am I correct in the best
>   way to organize the data in order to
>   create the 2-value line chart?

I don't know, but I'd test that idea by creating a table having that same structure. Not much point in rewriting the SQL until you know it's going to work.